# Is this possible to get all running containers id's in docker swarm services?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I am newbie in docker swarm mode, If I want more details about my swarm service , from command line I can run docker service ps "service name ", or from docker rest "/v2/services/my-ngx"

`[msreddy@swarmnode1 ~]$ docker service ps my-ngx
ID            NAME          IMAGE         NODE         DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE           ERROR                        PORTS
voj7fllhnmqb  my-ngx.1      nginx:latest  swarmnode1   Running        Running 26 minutes ago`

but it didn't give me container id. I want track containers form my swarm service is this possible ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Id returned by `docker service ps my-ngx` is the `<task_id>`
To get the container id, you can use `docker inspect -f "{{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}" <task_id>`

Comment: It seems than with newer API the ContainerID is not available

Comment: On Mac, `Version 17.09.1-ce-mac42` still supports this command

Comment: The container id output from the command in the answer is 64 characters long.  But `docker ps` outputs 12 character long IDs.  How does the 64 character long ID correspond to the 12 character ID?

Comment: +1 upvote on your answer thank you so much for this answer @prranay for this great command.  To answer my own question, the 12 character ID we see in Container IDs in the output of the ordinary `docker ps` command is the first 12 characters of the 64 character ID.  So it's a bit similar to git commit hashes which do something similar (if anyone wants a technical analogy).  I've also written a related Question & Answer here that credits your command: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12924/ (thanks again)

Answer (score 5):

The Solution of prranay work perfectly. To put it together with the question asked (bash):

```
for f in $(docker service ps -q my-ngx -f desired-state=running);do docker inspect --format '{{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}' $f; done
```

This lists all containers of the mentioned service `my-ngx`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here because I was trying to find the node with the given container ID.
I knocked this up to do that:

```
#!/bin/sh
docker node ps $(docker node ls -q) -f desired-state=running | sort -u | while read -r taskid widge taskname image host rem ; do echo "$taskid   $taskname   $image   $host   `docker inspect -f \"{{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}\" $taskid 2>/dev/null`"; done | grep $1
```

It's slow, but (without the grep) gives the container ID for every running task in the swarm.